# Query to List Encryption Certificate for Databases

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption, transparent-data-encryption

What certificate is being used to encrypt each of the databases on the instances.

I can get the data using the following but how do I write the queries

```
USE master
GO

-- this provides the list of certificates
SELECT * FROM sys.certificates


-- this provides the list of databases (encryption_state = 3) is encrypted
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys
 WHERE encryption_state = 3;
```

I noticed that columns sys.certifcates.thumbprint and sys.dm_database_encryption_keys.encryptor_thumbprint contain the same data.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can join on the certificate thumbprint:

```
use master;
go

select
    database_name = d.name,
    dek.encryptor_type,
    cert_name = c.name
from sys.dm_database_encryption_keys dek
left join sys.certificates c
on dek.encryptor_thumbprint = c.thumbprint
inner join sys.databases d
on dek.database_id = d.database_id;
```

My sample output:

```
database_name           encryptor_type    cert_name
=============           ==============    =========
tempdb                  ASYMMETRIC KEY    NULL
AdventureWorks2012TDE   CERTIFICATE       TdeCert
```

Comment: Note the `encryptor_type` field is only available on SQL 2012+.

Comment: This query does the same thing, but also includes non-encrypted DBs for comparison: `SELECT        d.name AS database_name, dek.encryptor_type, c.name AS cert_name
FROM            sys.databases AS d LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         sys.dm_database_encryption_keys AS dek ON dek.database_id = d.database_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         sys.certificates AS c ON dek.encryptor_thumbprint = c.thumbprint `

Answer (score 6):

For a more in-depth query that shows which databases are encrypted or not, their certificate and IMPORTANTLY if the encryption setup has actually completed or not. The encryption can sometimes take a long time to complete or get stuck.

```
SELECT D.name AS 'Database Name'
,c.name AS 'Cert Name'
,E.encryptor_type AS 'Type'
,case
    when E.encryption_state = 3 then 'Encrypted'
    when E.encryption_state = 2 then 'In Progress'
    else 'Not Encrypted'
end as state,
E.encryption_state, E.percent_complete, E.key_algorithm, E.key_length, E.* FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys E
right join sys.databases D on D.database_id = E.database_id
left join sys.certificates c ON E.encryptor_thumbprint=c.thumbprint
```